# Is it possible to type a property of each element that is part of an interface?

Tags: typescript

Suppose the following,

```
interface IButton {
  paramId: string;
  label: string;
}

const buttonsA: IButton[] = [
  {
    paramId: 'contract_id',
    label: 'Contract Number'
  },
  {
    paramId: 'employee_id',
    label: 'Employee'
  },
]

const buttonsB: IButton[] = [
  {
    paramId: 'member_group_id',
    label: 'Member Group ID'
  },
]
```

Is it possible to somehow type `paramId` in each element?

Something like,

```
interface IButton<T> {
  paramId: T;
  label: string;
}

const buttonsA: IButton<'contract_id', 'employee_id'>[] = [
  {
    paramId: 'contract_id',
    label: 'Contract Number'
  },
  {
    paramId: 'employee_id',
    label: 'Employee'
  },
]
. . .
```

Comment: To _constrain_ the types, so that invalid values aren't used?

Comment: Yes, so that I can reuse this one interface throughout my app, passing in specific values for each feature that utilizes it

Comment: If you do not need to enforce that _all_ of the given paramIds are used (I guess you _do_), you could pass a union to `IButton` (`IButton<'a' | 'b'>`) or create a union of `IButton`s, one for each paramId.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgQgV2MA9gOwDwBUoQB7ARoAmAzlAE4QCGx6ANiFKcBQJZoDmA2gLoB8UALxQA3gCgoUbgGkoHKAGsIIFADMoWXgC4xkqVDDUK1ALYxiurLN4BufVPrUARhHq6W7LvakBfe-7i4gDG6CxQzkioaKQAgrrwUegY3ADkoWis1MHAAPpsxKkANFCpEKZg9CggEBD5hQLC0voSBobGZha66ehZOfXFDlBOru6lAMK9JjlQAHIIpq4Ug35FLUNGJuaWpeWV1bUDa20jbt0AohVVNRArUL5rduJAA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: However, you could use some TS magic... Pass the wanted paramIds as a tuple and iterate over them, mapping them to a tuple of `IButton`s. Which I see @wonderflame just suggested :)

Comment: @wonderflame That seems to be it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have strict order you should pass a tuple of strings with the exactly same order:

```
const buttonsA: IButton<['contract_id', 'employee_id']> = [
  {
    paramId: 'contract_id',
    label: 'Contract Number',
  },
  {
    paramId: 'employee_id',
    label: 'Employee',
  },
];
```

Now, in the `IButton` let's change the constraint of the generic parameter to `readonly string[]`. `readonly` is needed to be able to pass `readonly` tuples, since `readonly unknown[]` is a superset of the `unknown[]`:

```
type IButton<T extends readonly string[]> = {}
```

By using mapped types we will map through the keys of the tuple and transform the shape of the element to `{paramId: ElementHere, label: string}`:

```
type IButton<T extends readonly string[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    paramId: T[K];
    label: string;
  };
};
```

Testing:

```
// [{
//     paramId: "contract_id";
//     label: string;
// }, {
//     paramId: "employee_id";
//     label: string;
// }]
type Result =  IButton<['contract_id', 'employee_id']>
```

Usage:

```
const buttonsA: IButton<['contract_id', 'employee_id']> = [
  {
    paramId: 'contract_id',
    label: 'Contract Number',
  },
  {
    paramId: 'employee_id',
    label: 'Employee',
  },
];

const buttonsB: IButton<['contract_id', 'employee_id']> = [
  {
    paramId: 'contract_id',
    label: 'Contract Number',
  },
  {
    paramId: 'invalid', // error
    label: 'Employee',
  },
];
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgQgV2MA9gOwDwBUoQB7ARoAmAzlAE4QCGx6ANiFKcBQJZoDmA2gLoB8UALxQA3gCgoUbgGkoHKAGsIIFADMoWXgC4xkqVDDUK1ALYxiurLN4BufVPrUARhHq6W7LvakBfe-7i4gD0wdISoQZSRibmllAARADG6KzUScAA+mzECfaRUU6u7sysHJz5Yb4ANHoFBjFmFroJEKZg9CggEBDZuZVRUEVuHmXeIVW84qCQUABKEKQI9MDCUvBIqJjcAOQpaGkZfTu1O20dXT3HAkH7LFDOm+ikAIK6G8joGLv7h1k5JygZ3anW6vQBAjW3H0EiijTiuj2qRMRwB1QcQxcIyBAGFkelVgA5BCmVwUE76GowjHw5pA86gq5ojHDEo7ACiIMuEApfnRdnEQA)